# Why do I get NaN as result of operation perfomed on three valid numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, nan

the following piece of Code returns `NaN` eventhough the values forming the expression are all valid numbers. I am quite confused and frustrated xD. What is my error here?

```
private getAllData = (res: any) => {
    this.setState({ priceBinance: res["binance"]["price"] })
    this.setState({ volumeBinance: res["binance"]["volume"] })
    this.setState({ highBinance: res["binance"]["high"] })
    this.setState({ lowBinance: res["binance"]["low"] })

    this.setState({ priceCrypto: res["crypto"]["price"] })
    this.setState({ volumeCrypto: res["crypto"]["volume"] })
    this.setState({ highCrypto: res["crypto"]["high"] })
    this.setState({ lowCrypto: res["crypto"]["low"] })

    this.setState({ priceKraken: res["kraken"]["price"] })
    this.setState({ volumeKraken: res["kraken"]["volume"] })
    this.setState({ highKraken: res["kraken"]["high"] })
    this.setState({ lowKraken: res["kraken"]["low"] })

    // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
    this.setState({ priceAverage: (this.state.priceBinance! + this.state.priceCrypto! + this.state.priceKraken!) / 3.0 })
    this.setState({ voulumeAverage: (this.state.volumeBinance! + this.state.volumeCrypto! + this.state.volumeKraken!) / 3.0 })
    this.setState({ highAverage: (this.state.highBinance! + this.state.highCrypto! + this.state.highKraken!) / 3.0 })
    this.setState({ lowAverage: (this.state.lowBinance! + this.state.lowCrypto! + this.state.lowKraken!) / 3.0 })
  }
```

Comment: Might depend on the contents of `res`, which you have not shared.

Comment: Please keep in mind that state update is asynchronous, you can not get the updated state value right away.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and actually *checking* the values of the variables you are using?

Comment: @derpirscher yes, I actually use those values to present them in the browser. All the other variables are valid numbers displayed on the screen. I didn't just imply that ;) but thank you

Comment: @ScottHunter the content are valid numbers... I checked that before asking this question. However, the asynchronous nature of updating the state may be the issue here, as pointed out by "@devd"

Comment: As others already noted, `setState` is asynchronous, so `this.state.xxx` may not yet be set when you use it at that position. Displaying them in the browser via react binding will of course work, because react takes care of that. Create a breakpoint (or a `console.log`) at that exact position of the code and check the value at that moment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous operation, meaning once you set a value to the state, it need not immediately update the state and, also you are force unwrapping the state values using `!`, for which you are getting `NaN` implies that the state value has not yet been updated when you're trying to access the state value, there are two approaches to solving this:

1. Invoke a callback once the state is updated(Not recommended, as you've to do it for every state value).
2. Use `res` property to get hold of the value directly and perform the desired operation.

```
this.setState({ priceAverage: (res["binance"]["price"] + res["crypto"]["price"] +res["kraken"]["price"]) / 3.0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is a asynchronous function because of which you are getting NaN.
Try setting up every state using res variable and not using this.state .